# Why cant i page scroll to see content outside the view in my html page?

Tags: html, css

I have a ionic app that im building one of the pages with bootstrap, i have very little experience with html and css, tryng to learn it now. My main page created via ionic CLI has page scroll, but this one that im making with bootstrap wont work this is the page html:

```
        <body>
    <div id=#myWorkContent>
      <div class="container-fluid">     

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-12">
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table hover">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Nervo</th>
                <th>Latência(ms)</th>
                <th>Amplitude Dista(mV)</th>
                <th>Amplitude Prox. (mV)</th>
                <th>Velocidade(m/s)</th>
                <th>Onda F(ms)</th>

              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <!-- long sequence of <tr><td>td><td></tr> inside -->
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body
```

ive tried this css >

```
    #myWorkContent{
            width: 100%;
            height:100%;   
            overflow-x: scroll;
            overflow-y: scroll;

        }
```

Comment: try adding relevant css as well.

Comment: What do you mean page scroll won't work? Please post your full html.

Comment: I zoom in on the browser, lowering the size of the view, and my content goes off view, and i cant scroll down to see it. thats the full html bseides my <head> that contains bootstrap script, and the table rows inside the table, that have only text on them.

Comment: Well...if i insert the code inside a <ion-content> the page scroll works...problem solved for the moment, but i would like to understand what is responsible for this in html? What is the equivalent without the ion-content.

Answer (score 0):

use `height:100vh and overflow:auto` overflow auto when the page dosen't need scroll, will not appear.

```
#myWorkContent{
    width: 100%;
    height:100vh;   
    overflow:auto;
 }
```